# LDAP Pac4j, disable PasswordPolicyControl

Tags: pac4j

I'm getting an error when validate user credentials against my LDAP system. Is there a way to disable the PasswordPolicyControl being called from LdaptiveAuthenticatorBuilder in v5.4.6?

authenticationResultCode=AUTHENTICATION_HANDLER_FAILURE, resultCode=INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_RIGHTS, matchedDN=, diagnosticMessage=The request control with Object Identifier (OID) "1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1" cannot be used due to insufficient access rights, referralURLs=[], messageID=3, controls=[]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you cannot disable the `PasswordPolicyControl`.

Though, if you are in a JEE environment, you may duplicate the `LdaptiveAuthenticatorBuilder` class in your project (same package, same name) and comment/remove the line: `handler.setAuthenticationControls(new PasswordPolicyControl());`. The overriden class will be taken into account before the one in the `pac4j-ldap` JAR.